# How can a probability measure satisfy the finite super additivity property?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

When introducing the Extention Theorem the book said:

"Let $J$ be a semialgebra of subsets of $\Omega$. Let P:$J$->[0,1] with P($\emptyset$) = 0 and P($\Omega$) = 1, satisfying the finite super additive property that.

P($\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}A_{i}$)$\geq\sum_{i=1}^{k}P(A_i)$ whenever $A_1,...,A_k \epsilon J$, and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}A_{i}\epsilon J $ and the ${A_i} are disjoint, and also the countable monotonicity property. "

I don't understand how this could be a probability measure. If I have these disjoint events, it shouldn't matter whether I take the probability of the union or the sum of the probability of the individual events. Under what circumstances would P($\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}A_{i}$)$>\sum_{i=1}^{k}P(A_i)$ be true?

Comment: If only $=$ is satisfied still $\geq$ is true.

Comment: So far, $P$ is not a probability measure.  It is merely a set-function with the stated properties.  You are setting up to construct a measure $\mu$, say.  The strict inequality can hold only for non-measurable sets.  If your original set-function $P$ has instances where $>$ holds, then either (1) some of the sets of $J$ will turn out to be non-measurable for $\mu$ or (2) for some elements  $E \in J$ will we will get $\mu(E) \ne P(E)$.